# probability of a mixed group standing in line

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

would appreciate your help checking if i did it cxorrectly

we have 7 girls and 13 boys standing in a line

1)x is a random variable defined by the number of the girls who stand in the last 5 places. what is p(x=i) for i=0,1,..5. my answer: $\frac{\binom{7}{i}\binom{13}{5-i}}{\binom{20}{5}}\:5!$

2)assuming that the places in the line are numbered. Y is the random variable defined by the smallest number of the location where a girl stands. what is p(y=j) when j=1,2,...,14? my answer: if we ave 7 girls, and we need the smallest number in where girls are located then it should be $\frac{\binom{13}{j-1}7}{\binom{20}{j}}$

3)if w is the random variable defined by the number of girls that to their right stands a boy, what is p(w=4)? i'm stuck on this one and i don't know how to solve it using the random variant w. would appreciate learning how to do it.

thank you very much for your help, did my best to elaborate and explain what i did

Comment: By the normal concept of a "line" (i.e., single file), the answer to (1) as stated is $P(X = 0) = 13/20, P(X = 1) = 7/20, P(X = i) = 0$ for $i > 1$. There can only be one person in the rightmost place in line. So $X = 0$ if that person is a boy, and $X = 1$ if that person is a girl. $X$ takes on no other value. So did you misunderstand the question, or reproduce it incorrectly here?

Comment: i think that the correct answer to 1) should be $\frac{\binom{7}{i}\binom{13}{5-i}}{\binom{20}{5}}$. is it correct now @PaulSinclair ?

Comment: So you believe that there is a $\dfrac{1001}{2548}$ probability that 2 girls are in the last place in line? One of the girls is standing on the other girl's head, maybe?? I already gave the answer to the question as it is stated, and explained why. You didn't address in any way what I said. Why would you hope that I would somehow think that a wildly different answer was now correct?

Comment: Paul Sinclair has already explained why your first answer is wrong.  Your second answer is also wrong.  It would help if you explained your reasoning in each case.

Comment: @PaulSinclair - fixed the question, sorry for my horrible english

Comment: @N.F.Taussig - fixed the question, sorry for my horrible english

Comment: I am suspicious that this is still not the correct phrasing for (1). Do you mean "$X$ is the number of girls after the last boy", maybe? As you have it now, a tail end such as "...,G,G,G,G,B" would give $X = 4$, But if $X$ is the number of girls after the last boy, then $X = 0$ for that line-up.

Comment: sorry for my bad english again lol. what i meant is {...,g,g,g,g,g}

Comment: This doesn't make sense. (Please don't apologize for bad english again - I understand that - I am just trying to help you correct the problem.) If the last 5 places are "g,g,g,g,g", (all girls), then $X = 5$. We cannot choose $X = 0$. That does not match what you said $X$ means, nor does it match my suggestion. By "...,G,G,G,G,B" I was giving an EXAMPLE of one way the boys and girls could be lined up. I am asking what value of $X$ would this example have? By the current version of (1), it would have $X = 4$. Is that what $X$ should be for this case? If not, then (1) is not correct, yet.

Comment: only ggggg, no boy in the end. we choose 5, not 4(ggggb)